# WCF Servcie only worked on local computer of IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I created a website on IIS at 192.168.0.163, and published a wcf service application on it, I can get wsdl of service through hostname `hostname:port/Service.svc?wsdl` and ip address `192.168.0.163:port/Service.svc?wsdl`, but `hostname.domain.com:port/Service.svc?wsdl` not work, on another computer in same domain.

At the end of wsdl, I found the service address is `ws://hostname.domain.com:port/Service.svc`.

In client, I added service reference by vs2015, in `app.config` the service address also is `ws://hostname.domain.com:port/Service.svc`, and I can only connect to service from local computer which IIS stays, calling from another computer will cause a exception:

> The remote endpoint requested an address for acknowledgements that is
>   not the same as the address for application messages. The channel
>   could not be opened because this is not supported. Ensure the endpoint
>   address used to create the channel is identical to the one the remote
>   endpoint was set up with.

If I change address to `hostname:port/Service.svc` or `192.168.0.163:port/Service.svc`, then I faulted to access the service from both computers with same error.

Close firewall can't solve the problem.

How to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Solved after add hostname in IIS bindings.